# Uncaught TypeError: number is not a function using length

Tags: jquery

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
console.log($(".name").text().length());
    });
```

number is not a function? I selected the right class.. why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.lenght` is Property which return the number of elements in the `jQuery object` so just remove () from lenght.

```
console.log($(".name").text().length);
```

[Refer this `jQuery` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/length/)

Comment: .length is not jQuery specific, it returns the length of an array, string length, etc

Comment: @Alex check out documentation of jQuery.

Comment: @Harshall I have seen the docs, but still `.length` is no jQuery property. It existed long time before jQuery existed :) jQuery is just so kind and mentions `length` in their docs, but it works with all arrays. And each jQuery object is just an array. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length

Answer (score 2):

`.length` is not a function, it's a property, so dont use `()`:

```
console.log($(".name").text().length);
```

Also, does `.name` exist?